# how do i create a directory in perl which includes current timestamp as EPOCH

Tags: perl

The direcrory structure that i am creating is thus:

```
my $startTime = `date +%s`;
my $startTime2 = $startTime + 10;
chomp($startTime2);
print "startTime2: " . "$startTime2";
my $pwd = getcwd();

#my $PWD=system("pwd");
print "Current Working Directory: " . "$pwd\n";
my $logdir = "$pwd" . "/load-logs";
print "Log Directory: " . "$logdir\n";
#chmod( 755, $logdir ) or die "Couldn't chmod $logdir: $!";

mkdir("$logdir/$startTime2", 777) || print $!;
#print "start Time in epoc : "."$startTime";
#mkdir("$startTime3", 777) || print $!;
#system("mkdir \$logdir/$startTime");

my $reqlogfile  = "$logdir/$startTime2/req.log";
print "reqlogfile: " . "$reqlogfile\n";
my $resplogfile = "$logdir/$startTime2/resp.log";
print "resplogfile: " . "$resplogfile\n";
```

now, mkdir("$logdir/$startTime2", 777) || print $!;
does not create a directory which has the current value of $startTime2 under $logdir

Comment: <pre>my $startTime = `date +%s`;</pre> is absolutely wasteful. Just use `my $startTime = time();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem may be that your `$logdir` wasn't created, so it's best to ensure it is created.

Also, it's best to make sure the `umask` is reset so that if you `chmod` to `0777`, the parent shell's `umask` doesn't interfere with the `umask` in the script.

Perl's `mkdir` doesn't work as the shell's `mkdir -p` (which creates intermediate directories if they do not exist). One could use `mkpath` from File::Path, or simply ensure the intermediate path is created, as I show below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;

my $start_time   = time;   # equivalent to `date +%s`, less a shell out ;)
my $start_time_2 = $start_time + 10;

umask 000; # ensure the permissions you set are the ones you get

my $pwd = getcwd();
print "Current Working Directory: $pwd\n";

my $logdir = "$pwd/load-logs";
print "Log Directory: $logdir\n";

mkdir $logdir
    or die "Cannot mkdir $logdir: $!"
    unless -d $logdir ;
chmod 0755, $logdir or die "Cannot chmod 0755 $logdir: $!";

mkdir("$logdir/$start_time_2", 0777)
    or die "Cannot mkdir $logdir/$start_time_2: $!"
    unless -d "$logdir/$start_time_2";

my $reqlogfile  = "$logdir/$start_time_2/req.log";
print "reqlogfile: $reqlogfile\n";
my $resplogfile = "$logdir/$start_time_2/resp.log";
print "resplogfile: $resplogfile\n";
```

The above (with strict, warnings, etc) works for me:

```
~/t$ perl t.pl
Current Working Directory: /home/mf/t
Log Directory: /home/mf/t/load-logs
reqlogfile: /home/mf/t/load-logs/1293636556/req.log
resplogfile: /home/mf/t/load-logs/1293636556/resp.log
```

Launching it multiple times doesn't die, and creates the directories (and chmods them) if needed. You can check that via `ls -la load-logs/`.